# How to record a call in Android pie?

Tags: java, android

Basically I've done call recording but it's not working up to Oreo.
I read an article in Wich google stop call recording in up to Oreo anyone have any idea how to record call in Android pie?
Code comments will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

The official call recording API was removed in Android 6.0 Marshmallow. 
There was a workaround in native code around the root requirement, which worked until Android 8.1, but Google patched it in Android 9 Pie.

Call recording is not allowed from Android 6 Marshmallow. There was a workaround in native code around the root requirement, which worked until Android 8.1.

You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://bitbucket.org/copluk/acr/issues/2418/kb-android-9-p-call-recording-issues).

Comment: Is there any official link for blocking the call record in Oreo?